# c++ getline and ignore

Tags: c++, cin, getline

Can anyone please, tell me why does the following code works, when I use **cin.ignore(0,'\n')** but not when I use **cin.ignore(100, '\n')** :/

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


main () {
  char arr[100], brr[100];
  string srr;

  cout << "Enter a string : ";
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(0, '\n');
  cin.getline(arr, 100);
  cin.getline(brr, 100);
  cout << "brr : " << brr << endl;
  srr = string(arr);
  cout << "Converted to string : " << srr << endl;
  string find;
  cout << "Enter something to find : ";
  getline(cin, find);
  cout << endl;
  if (srr.find(find) != string::npos)
    cout << "Found ! at " << srr.find(find) << " " << endl;
  else
    cout << "Sorry ! not found :/ \n";
}
```

Comment: What do you think `cin.ignore(0,'\n')` do?

Comment: See: [std::basic_istream::ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: well, from what I've read cin.ignore, takes two parameters 'n' and a 'delim'. It is supposed to extract 'n' chars and break on the 'delim'.

Comment: David, if count is the number of chars to extract having count as 0 must not extract any character, but it does ?!

Comment: Yup. So if `n` is 0, the line does nothing, and when it's 100, you basically ignore the next line.

Comment: @FeiXiang sorry, for if I am a noob but can you elaborate ?

Comment: @CerealKiller • which part do you need elaboration on?  The "does nothing" part, or the "ignore the next line" part?

Comment: See the answer I posted.

Comment: @Eljay the ignore the next line part, do you mean that, cin.ignore, just simply does not acknowledge the first 100, chars if I were to write ignore(100,'\n')

Comment: @CerealKiller • In the case that the line is greater than 100 character, yes.  In the case that the line is less than 100 characters, it will stop at the delimiter.

Comment: You don't need `cin.ignore` here. Remove it and your life will be much simpler. The situation where you need it occurs when you mix formatted extractors (`operator>>`) with `getline`; formatted extractors don't remove whitespace following whatever they extracted, so in the simplest cases there's a newline character in the input stream after the extraction, and a subsequent `getline` will read that empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `cin.ignore(0,'\n')`, you're saying "Ignore the characters in the stream until you have ignored 0 characters or you reach a '\n'". Since you told the stream to ignore a maximum of 0 characters, it does nothing.

When you write `cin.ignore(100, '\n')`, you're saying "Ignore the characters in the stream until you have ignored 100 characters or you reach a '\n'". There probably isn't going to be 100 characters, so you're basically ignoring characters until the next newline. If you think about it, you're ignoring the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::ignore` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

> Extracts and discards characters from the input stream until and including delim.
>
> ...
>
> **count**     -   number of characters to extract

When you use `cin.ignore(0, '\n');`, nothing gets extracted. It is a do-nothing call.

When you use `cin.ignore(100, '\n');`, all characters up to 100 characters or until `'\n'` is encountered are extracted and discarded.